# Apache Spark Connector for SQL Server and Azure SQL

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I'm trying to write data from Azure Databricks to Azure SQL using this connector - com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0, but getting the below error message -

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, 10.139.64.4, executor 0): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ISQLServerBulkData

Is this spark connector working with Azure Databricks to Azure SQL? have any one tested this?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Microsoft publishes only jar for connector itself, and it doesn't include JDBC driver that is required for connector.  If you build code yourself, build system produces the `assembly` artifact, but that could be used, but it's isn't published.  You can workaround the problem by adding the JDBC driver explicitly (the `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8` coordinate), like this (for spark-submit/spark-shell/pyspark, etc.):

```
bin/spark-shell --packages \
  com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0-alpha,com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8
```

or adding two libraries via UI

Comment: I created the build file using SBT and included it in library and also the above steps, but getting the below error message - Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, 10.139.64.4, executor 0): java.io.InvalidClassException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.SQLServerBulkJdbcOptions; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5653142344326218886, local class serialVersionUID = -2929844964663823362

Comment: hmmm... check that your version is matching to version in MS SQL connector

Comment: We were able to use this connector for writing data to Azure SQL, but the performance comparing the JDBC connector..it took 20 minutes to load 8.7M records..

Comment: you can tune the batching parameters as described in the documentation

Comment: yes we have included those parameters - try:
  df_merge.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("bulkCopyBatchSize","400000") \
    .option("bulkCopyTableLock","true") \
    .option("bulkCopyTimeout","600") \

Comment: Is there any other recommendation for this? or any other parameters we need to specify..

Comment: it's hard to say without looking into logs, etc. It's not clear if bottleneck is on the Databricks/Spark side, or MS SQL side.

Comment: I'm getting an error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.schemaString(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;)Ljava/lang/String;`

Answer (score 0):

As Alex mentioned, using `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8` is one thing but also you need proper version of [MS' Spark SQL Connector](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector)

`com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0-alpha` and `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8` did not work for my case as I'm using AWS Glue 3.0 (which is Spark 3.1)

I had to switch to `com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0` as it's Spark 3.1 compatible.

```
def write_df_to_target(self, df, schema_table):
    spark = self.gc.spark_session
    spark.builder.config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0').getOrCreate()
    credentials = self.get_credentials(self.replica_connection_name)

    df.write \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", credentials["url"] + ";databaseName=" + self.database_name) \
        .option("dbtable", schema_table) \
        .option("user", credentials["user"]) \
        .option("password", credentials["password"]) \
        .option("batchsize","100000") \
        .option("numPartitions","15") \
        .save()
```